# Paraview-Creation of 3D body from points

Tags: excel, 3d, paraview

I want ask how to create an object (coherent body), if I have 3 excel files (approximately 1mil. Rows each) with X Y Z coordinate. After importing to Paraview I have ‘object’ as in figure below, it consist of 25 ‘planes’ which consist of points from excel files. I need to make from this planes one object with coherent body, basically wrap this planes with something. Is it possible with use of some filters in Paraview or do I need some programmable filter ? I have tried few things but the result was not satisfying.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apply **Table to Points** filter to generate a point set and then apply the **Delaunay 3D** filter to get a surface from those points.